# passing a return statement into another function in a class

Tags: python, class, function, return

I have the following code that I am using to send a message from a gmail account to another gmail account:

```
 import smtplib

 class GmailSmpt:

    global server
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com','587')
    def __init__(self,sendfrom,sendto,usrname,pswd):
        self.sendfrom = sendfrom
        self.sendto = sendto
        self.usrname = usrname
        self.pswd = pswd
    def connect(self):
        msg = 'this is a test message'
        server.starttls()
        server.login(self.usrname,self.pswd)
        server.sendmail(self.sendfrom,self.sendto,msg)
        print ("your email has been sent")
    def quit(self):
        server.quit()



    first = GmailSmpt('sendfrom','sendto',
    'usrname','pswd')

    first.connect()
    first.quit()
```

Instead of having a global variable server, I would like to use "return server" in the "connect" function and then pass server on to the "quit" function.  How would I put that into the parameter of def quit(self, ?)?  What I would normally do in a non object oriented program is "def quit(self,connect), but in this case I want to be able to call def connect() and def quit() separately.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about make `server` an attribute of each instance of `GmailSmpt`:

```
class GmailSmpt:
    def __init__(self,sendfrom,sendto,usrname,pswd):
        self.server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com','587')
        ...
```

After all, `server.login` uses `self.usrname`, and `self.pswd`, so `server`'s domain of relevance is bound to one instance of `GmailSmpt`, so it makes sense to make `server` an attribute of that instance also.

PS. If you make `server` an attribute of `self`, then you'll also have to change `server` --> `self.server` in the other methods.

Comment: Thank you so much.  That makes a lot of sense.  I'm just starting to wrap my head around classes so this is very helpful.